# What is the difference between `MAX(column + 1)` and `MAX(column) + 1`

Tags: mysql

I know I should be writing `MAX(column) + 1` in my queries rather than `MAX(column +1)`. However, by mistake I wrote the wrong one and it seems to prevent a deadlock issue that I was having.

Couldn't find an explanation on this after digging for sometimes. Do point me to the write direction if this is already answered or looking forward to learn some new interesting things.

Answer (score 1):

`max(column)+1` will compute max value of the column and then adds 1 to the results
`max(column+1)` will compute max value on column value+1

Tables meta data/index will be used when you use `max(column)` but `max(column+1)` needs to scan all the rows and compute the values one by one. So good to use `max(column)+1`

Comment: So when I write `SELECT MAX(column + 1) FROM table FOR UPDATE` in a transaction on `REPEATABLE READ` isolation; what is the locking situation ? For some reason this doesn't give any deadlock errors in concurrent situation but very slow (the reason you explained earlier). But this: `SELECT MAX(column ) +1  FROM table FOR UPDATE` does. Any reason?

Comment: FOR UPDATE locks rows it "touches" when executing your query. `MAX(column )+1` can use index over `column` (or similar depending to WHERE clause) so it can lock only few rows (not sure if only one or some gap etc, definitely not many). `MAX(column + 1)` cannot use index so well, so it has to do full table/index scan and locks "everything" - so any other query just has no way to lock anything else which might collide -> no deadlock probable, but slow execution and lot of waiting

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: The execution time is almost 10 times in MAX(column+1) than MAX(column)+1 ; so I THINK jkavalik 's answer explain the situation best. Thanks Guys.

Comment: @Maz for better understanding try checking those queries with [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) - that will tell you how it is executed and which indexes it uses.

Comment: Yah, did that. Interestingly enough it seems `MAX(column+1)` uses the index but the other one `MAX(column)+1` only shows: `Select tables optimized away`.

Comment: @Maz that means it was able to find the max value just from index structure, not looking at any concrete row at all. But I have no idea what that means for locking.

Comment: @Maz what exactly is the purpose of `SELECT MAX(column) FROM table FOR UPDATE`? Do you want some rows to be locked? Or the whole table? And if the real question is about `FOR UPDATE` behaviour, you should add that in the question, not just in comments.

Comment: ok, here is the scenario: I need to lock the `MAX(column) SELECT `query value for the transaction because it is a unique sequential sequence number; no gap is allowed. Hence the usage of `FOR UPDATE` in a `READ COMMITTED` mode to avoid deadlocks (If I use `REPEATABLE READ` I have deadlocks) and not locking the gaps.